# Проблема в установке WxWidgets[Как включить с++ 2011?]

Tags: c++, gcc, компилятор, wxwidgets

Это то что мне выдает в консоли после 3ей команды:

> cd %WXWIN%\build\msw
>
> mingw32-make -f makefile.gcc clean
>
> mingw32-make -f makefile.gcc BUILD=debug SHARED=0 MONOLITHIC=0 UNICODE=1 WXUNIV=0
>
> mingw32-make -f makefile.gcc BUILD=release SHARED=0 MONOLITHIC=0 UNICODE=1 WXUNIV=0

```
from ../../src/common/any.cpp:18:
C:/TDM-GCC-32/lib/gcc/mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/bits/c++0x_warning.h:32:2: error
: #error This file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011 st
andard. This support is currently experimental, and must be enabled with the -st
d=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options.
 #error This file requires compiler and library support for the \
  ^
In file included from ..\..\include/wx/string.h:46:0,
                 from ..\..\include/wx/any.h:19,
                 from ../../src/common/any.cpp:18:
..\..\include/wx/strvararg.h:350:18: error: 'is_enum' in namespace 'std' does no
t name a template type
     typedef std::is_enum<T> is_enum;
                  ^
..\..\include/wx/strvararg.h:354:54: error: 'is_enum' was not declared in this s
cope
     enum { value = wxFormatStringSpecifierNonPodType<is_enum::value>::value };
                                                      ^
..\..\include/wx/strvararg.h:354:68: error: template argument 1 is invalid
     enum { value = wxFormatStringSpecifierNonPodType<is_enum::value>::value };
                                                                    ^
makefile.gcc:11712: recipe for target 'gcc_mswud\baselib_any.o' failed
mingw32-make: *** [gcc_mswud\baselib_any.o] Error 1

C:\wxWidgets-3.0.2\build\msw>
```

Помогите пожалуйста!

Answer (score 1):

```
cd %WXWIN%\build\msw

mingw32-make -f makefile.gcc clean

mingw32-make -f makefile.gcc BUILD=debug SHARED=0 MONOLITHIC=0 UNICODE=1 WXUNIV=0 CXXFLAGS="-std=gnu++11"

mingw32-make -f makefile.gcc BUILD=release SHARED=0 MONOLITHIC=0 UNICODE=1 WXUNIV=0 CXXFLAGS="-std=gnu++11"
```

Или `CXXFLAGS="-std=gnu++14"` если последний стандарт, 
зависит от версии компилятора.

Comment: это не решает проблему, но я давно решил ее!

Comment: @MaximPro так поделитесь ответом. Возможно, он кому-то будет полезен.